# Adding an external css depending on a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a hidden div which contains a value in (1,2,3).
I want to get the innerhtml & depending on the value want to add a specific css file.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     if($('#tVal').html()=='1'){
      $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="../common/css/theme1.css" type="text/css" />');
     }  
    });

    <div id="tVal">1</div>
```

Not being able to identify my fault. Please help!

*** THE CODE WORKS.. It was a temporary firefox tantrum! Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: What goes wrong? [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/yq4w1z8v/) shows that the the stylesheet does get added to the head.

Comment: So what returns `$('#tVal').html()`? Maybe trim it

Comment: `$('#tVal').html()`'s return is the problem here for sure. Gotta check what it returns.

Comment: Sorry about the mishap. don't know why it happened. But I checked on chrome it worked & on firefox it was not working at first. But I restarted it n now it's working -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried that exact code and it works fine to me. Would you please share with us some more of your code? console outputs? Have you tried placing some alert or console.log inside the if to see if the conditional evaluates to true? If it doesnt, add a `else{alert('a');}` to see if the if is being ran. Have you correctly included JQuery library?

I am helping as much as I can with that very little information.

Comment: it works. it was my bad. firefox does that sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this.

```
var $head = $("head");
var $headlinklast = $head.find("link[rel='stylesheet']:last");
var newlinkElement = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/yourFile.css' type='text/css' media='screen'>";
if ($headlinklast.length){
   $headlinklast.after(newlinkElement);
}
else {
   $head.append(newlinkElement);
}
```

Comment: Can you add some words to explain your answer?